# React dynamically generate an M x 3 grid of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically create a grid of components with JSON data that is (data length / 3) x 3. So it'd look something like this.

[image]

The size of the components in each grid will be static, but the padding around them should be dynamic depending on parent div size/screen size. Padding should also only be on right if it's not in the far right column. Any advice? Any NPM components anyone know of to make this easy?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using Grid system of CSS. Here's a [complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: awesome article, but I don't know how big the JSON array will be before hand so I need to generate dynamically still

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? You simply map over the array of objects and display one by one... If your concern is then the array might be too long that you have to implement pagination or infinite scroll... Is that the issue?